# Cannot connect device to android studio (device name is showing in the bar at the top)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, adb

Please check the image for reference:
[android studio emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G19W.png).

Please help if you know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some simple default solutions you can try

Please make sure that you installed the Samsung device drivers because its really important to have communication.

1. Try to **restart** the device.
2. Go to **settings>about>**tap on **Build version** seven times.
3. Then there will be **developer option** in settings.
4. GO to it and enable **USB debuggings.**
5. Open the termial in android studio and type the following

   adb devices
   if you see a dialog in device click allow .

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have defined android SDK path

you can define it this way:

```
flutter config --android-sdk ANDROID_SDK_PATH
```

but use "ANDROID_SDK_PATH" = your path, for example:

```
flutter config --android-sdk C:\Users\%youruser%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```